# Why a rejected parameter of a promise works outside of its scope?

Tags: javascript, express, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, ecmascript-2017

See, a promise have two parameters **resolved** and **rejected**. So by calling **then**, you are passing it 2 parameters.

```
router.route('/issue/add').post((req,res) => 
{
    let issue= new Issue(req.body);

    issue.save().then((issue) => 
        {
            res.status(200).json({'issue': 'Added Successfully'});
        }).catch(err => 
        {
            res.status(400).send('Failed to create a requested record');
        });
});
```

but in the code above **issue** is passed and mapped to **resolved** but for **rejected** an **err** param need to be passed in **then** but instead it is passed in **catch** and works. Why?

Comment: what do you mean it works? it can't work for both. Either status 200 will be responded or 400, won't be both

Comment: `issue` is the resolved value of a fulfilled promise ... `err` is the rejection reason for a rejected promise ... the names of the function parameters are not at all relevant ... the `issue` of `let issue` is **NOT** the same thing as the `issue`  in `.then((issue)` ... in other words `.then((result) =>` would mean the argument named `result` has the result of a successful `.save`

Comment: `So by calling then, you are passing it 2 parameters` - yes, `.then` takes two arguments, an onfulfilled function and an onrejected function ... however your code doesn't even do that

Comment: Both parameters of `then` are optional. You don't have to pass a `onreject` callback.

Comment: "*a promise have two parameters resolved and rejected.*" - what do you mean? A promise is an object, not a function, it doesn't have any parameters at all.